# Significance Tests for mean of means

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design

I have a metric which is calculated daily (e.g. Average Revenue per Day per User), so over 1 month this will yield 30 samples. I would like to test if the difference between experiment groups for this metric is statistically significant, but I'm not sure if I can since I would be testing the mean of 30 means.

Do I have to treat those any differently with respect to statistical tests and can anyone include helpful links with supporting docs on the subject?

(Edit)
**Example**

Experiment: Test if offering gift in game has impact on overall game revenue

Cohorts:

- Control (no offer)
- Variant A (Offer free 10K coins once a day)
- Variant B (Offer option of free 5K coins **or** $2 purchase for 50K coins once a day)

Target metric: Average Revenue per Day per User (ARPDAU). For example:

- Day 1 - `$100 Rev / 20 Users = $5 ARPDAU`
- Day 2 - `$200 Rev / 50 Users = $4 ARPDAU`
- Day 3 - `$80 Rev / 80 Users = $1 ARPDAU`
- ARPDAU Mean = `$3.33`

Comment: The fact of being means isn't really a problem. If these are gathered daily, you will have autocorrelation to deal with, though.

Comment: How many experiment groups ? which metric you want to test ?  what is definition of your experiment group? what is your control group. The question is too vague to discern the objective of your problem. pl. write more and be specific.

Comment: More details added, hopefully that helps.